# WinForms on Tabpage selected run method in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, tabcontrol

My Tabcontrol has 3 Tabpages. I am currently in Tabpage 1, when I would select Tabpage 2. I want to run a method in my UserControl assigned to that Tabpage. You could call this a "Focus" listener. How would I implement this? Or is this possible at all?

**Edit:**

Lets say I have a file named "UserControl1.cs" In here there is a method `OnFocus()` I would like to call this method when its Tabpage becomes the active tab. I am assigning the UserControl to the Tabpage like this:

```
        // AllOpenUserControls = List<UserControl> // With the active pages

        TabPage newPage = new TabPage();
        newPage.Text = title;
        newPage.AutoScroll = true;
        newPage.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        newPage.Controls.Add(userControl);
        AllOpenUserControls.Add(userControl);

        tabControl.TabPages.Add(newPage);
```

Comment: Do you mean this?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @MatSnow that is a beginning, but how would I run that method inside of my UserControl when that listener is being called?

Comment: Add an eventhandler for `TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-create-event-handlers-at-run-time-for-windows-forms

Comment: @MatSnow I know this part, but I don't now how to select the right Tabpage and run a method inside of that

Comment: With `TabControl.SelectedTab`? Seems, your question is missing some important details. Instead of asking a new question in every comment, edit your question and add the relevant details and code parts.

Comment: @MatSnow edited the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159239/discussion-between-finiox-and-matsnow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `EventHandler` for `SelectedIndexChanged` here:

```
...
tabControl.TabPages.Add(newPage);
tabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(userControl.OnFocus);
```

Your `OnFocus`-method should look like this:

```
public void OnFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tc = (TabControl)sender;
    if (tc.SelectedTab == this.Parent)
    {
        //Parent-Tab is selected, do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it. In my case I actually am extending an object called `BaseUserControl` I've made the `public virtual void OnFocus()` in there. In the actual UserControl `UserControl1 : BaseUserControl` I overrided this method and now it works.